# Using Iterator to call a multiple argument method

Tags: java

I'm attempting to sort a list of shapes by area.  I'm using an Iterator to move through the list and call Rectangle.calculateArea on each element of the list, but the printed list does not output the area of each element.  The output is instead a hexadecimal reference to each element.  Below is the output, followed by the code.  How can I get my output to display calculated area?

Rectangle Areas:
Rectangle@15db9742
Rectangle@6d06d69c
Rectangle@7852e922
Rectangle@4e25154f
Rectangle@70dea4e

```
public class RectangleSortTest {
public static void main (String[] args) {
List<Rectangle> list = new ArrayList<>();
//Create Rectangle ArrayList

list.add(new Rectangle(4, 3));
list.add(new Rectangle(3, 3));
list.add(new Rectangle(4, 4));
list.add(new Rectangle(5, 1));
list.add(new Rectangle(1, 1));
//Add Rectangle elements to Rectangle list



calculateListArea(list);
//Calculates area for each rectangle element

System.out.print("Rectangle Areas:");
printList(list);
//Print rectangle list after area calculation


}

private static void calculateListArea(List<Rectangle> list) {//Calculates Rectangle list areas
    ListIterator<Rectangle> iterator = list.listIterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Rectangle rectangleElement = iterator.next();
        Rectangle.calculateArea(rectangleElement.getWidth(), rectangleElement.getHeight());
    }
}

private static void printList(List<Rectangle> list) {//Print Rectangle list
    for (Rectangle element: list) {
        System.out.printf("%n%s", element);
    }   
}
```

}

Comment: You are calling `calculateArea` but not doing anything with the result. Then in your `System.out.printf` statement you are just printing the rectangle, not its area.

Comment: You are printing the instance of rectangle not the result of calculation. Make a method that returns the result and use it in your System.out.printf.